# what will be the rate of effusion of oxygen gas at a pressure of 1760 torr and temperature of 227 °C?

Tags: physical-chemistry

The rate of effusion of hydrogen gas at 880 torr and 227°C is 8 torr/min . 
what will be the rate of effusion of oxygen gas at a pressure of 1760 torr and temperature of 227 °C?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the rate of effusion of a gas with only that little information.

With that information you can only tell the ratio of the rates of effusion at two different conditions.

You should have included what you thought about the question and your thought process. This is not a homework solving website but a site to ask conceptual queries.